# Access SQL statement: if no entries are valid, return the last one

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

I am trying to get a SQL statement which solves the following issue.

I have a table "calendar" which includes only one column "date". This table has 12 entries for each month in 2019 (01.31.2019, 02.28.2019 and so on). The second table "values" (which I get from an ERP system) has three columns, "from", "to" and "amount" (e.g. 01.01.2019, 06.30.2019, 50 and 08.01.2019, 08.31.2019, 100).

I have this simple statement which checks which entry is valid on the specific date:

```
SELECT Calendar.Date, Values.From, Values.To, Values.Amount
FROM Calendar, [Values]
WHERE Calendar.Date >= Values.From 
  AND Calendar.Date <= Values.To;
```

There is no valid entry (in the table "values") for July, September, October, November and December.

In the case there is no valid entry the last entry should be used. In July it would be 50 and for September, October ... it would be 100.

I tried subquery and left joins, but I never got the wanted result.

Has anybody an idea or better a solution for this issue. I appreciate any support

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: https://ufile.io/qqitk

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for an additional join on the `Values` table, that will return the last entry before the current date. When the first `(LEFT) JOIN` does not succeed, you can use the result returned by the second one.

To locate the last entry before the current date, we can use a `NOT EXISTS` condition with a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT 
    c.Date, 
    Nz(v.From, v1.From) AS [From], 
    Nz(v.To, v1.To) AS [To], 
    Nz(v.Amount, v1.Amount) AS [Amount]
FROM Calendar AS c
LEFT JOIN [Values] AS v 
    ON c.Date >= v.From AND c.Date <= v.To
LEFT JOIN [Values] AS v1 
    ON v1.To < c.Date
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM [Values] v2 WHERE v2.To < c.Date AND v2.To > v1.To
    )
```

PS : it's been a good practice for a long time in SQL to avoid old-school, implicit `JOIN`s, and always use explicit `JOIN`s.

Comment: I always get a syntax error but I can't see the cause.

Comment: @Paintitblack3k : which error are you getting exactly ?

Comment: @Paintitblack3k : I fixed a glitch in column names, let me know if this works for your now... Thanks !

Comment: I get "Syntaxerror (missing operator) in ''." (hopefully I translated it excactly). Maybe it depands on the MS Access version?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a LEFT JOIN and a subquery to get the last amount:

```
SELECT c.Date, v.From, v.To, 
Nz(
  v.Amount, 
  (SELECT MAX([Values].Amount) FROM [Values] WHERE [Values].From = 
    (SELECT MAX([Values].From) FROM [Values] WHERE [Values].From <= c.Date))
) AS Amount
FROM Calendar AS c LEFT JOIN [Values] AS v
ON c.Date>=v.From AND c.Date<=v.To;
```

Comment: This works pretty well. I will stress it tomorrow with some other case. With the case which I described it works awesame.

Comment: `SELECT c.Date, v.From, v.To, Nz(
  v.Amount, 
  (SELECT Top 1 [Values].Amount FROM [Values] WHERE [Values].From <=c.Date ORDER BY v.From DESC)
) AS Amount
FROM Calendar AS c LEFT JOIN [Values] AS v ON (c.Date>=v.From) AND (c.Date<=v.To);` What about only one subquery with TOP 1 and ORDER BY [Values].FROM DESC.This doesn't work, but why?

Comment: TOP 1 is meant to return a resultset for ACCESS, use MAX() without ORDER BY:`SELECT c.Date, v.From, v.To, Nz( v.Amount, (SELECT MAX( [Values].Amount) FROM [Values] WHERE [Values].From <=c.Date)) AS Amount FROM Calendar AS c LEFT JOIN [Values] AS v ON (c.Date>=v.From) AND (c.Date<=v.To);`